# File handling using arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, file-io

I have some simple C code. I am using Xcode for Mac OS and I can not seem to get this simple code to build. I keep getting the error "Use of undeclared identifier" for an array I'd like to print to the file called data. Any advice would be great.

Made sure I included all headers, checked multiple times fprintf syntax. I know that the array 'a[]' is declared so I am confused on the build error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void){

    int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int i;

    FILE  *fpout;

    fpout = fopen("numbers.txt", "w");

    for (i=0;i<4;i++){

        fprintf(fpout, "%d ", &a[i]); //says use of undeclared identifier 'a'
    }

    fclose(fpout);
    return 0;          
}
```

This code is to simply output "1,2,3,4,5" to the file called numbers.txt however the code will not build because inside the fprintf statement, the array 'a' said to be an undeclared identifier.

[image]

Comment: Don't know why it's giving that error, but it should just be `a[i]`, not `&a[i]`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. That's what was thinking. I'll go ahead and run this this on codeblocks.